# (Using JScroll Bars) Write a program the uses scroll bars to select the foreground color for a label

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

can someone please help me write a program that uses scroll bars to select the foreground color for a label. Three horizontal scroll bars are used for selecting the red, green, and blue components of the color. Use a title border on the panel that holds the scroll bars.

The foreground color changes in the label as you adjust the scroll bars.

Comment: Sure, but why don't you tell us and show us what you've done so far. Also you'll want to provide details of the problem and the environment. Are you using Swing, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is a JSlider.  Take a look at the example here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider using `JColorChooser`, as described in [*How to Use Color Choosers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).